# How to show effect on like button like facebook shows

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like, effect

I have a layout in which I have like button which is a simple textview and I have applied onclick event on this. Now I want to show the same effect which facebook shows when like button in facebook android app get clicked on the news feeds.

How can I do this in my android application. Please help me if you have any idea here.

Comment: You wanna implement Facebook like button or just that effect?

Comment: Create a selector drawable for like/unlike using selected and unselected drawable.

Comment: No, I have textview and just want to add effect on that textview like facebook shows on it's like button.

Comment: @PrithnirajNicyone Do you mean the animation on the drawable of facebook like button?

Answer (score 0):

Use selector if you want to give a highlight effect only when the button in touched.

Save this as an xml drawable and assign this drawable to the button :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_white_09_rectangle_unpressed" android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_white_09_rectangle_pressed" android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_white_09_rectangle_pressed" android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_white_09_rectangle_unpressed" />
</selector>
```

Create 2 other drawable xml files which is being used by the above xml.
btn_white_09_rectangle_unpressed.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle"
            >
            <corners
                android:radius="9dp"/>

            <gradient
                android:angle="45"
                android:endColor="#27FFFFFF"
                android:startColor="#18FFFFFF"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

btn_white_09_rectangle_pressed.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle"
            >
            <corners
                android:radius="11dp"/>
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:endColor="#09FFFFFF"
                android:startColor="#02FFFFFF"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

If you want to change the background of the button(and not revert) when user clicks on it then you have to do it through code.
Use the following code in your onClick()

```
your_button.setBackgroundResource(R.id.desired_drawable);
```